# foreign keys: number of columns not equal to referenced columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error from oracle that says "number of referencing columns must match referenced columns."
I want my column **recorded_on** in the table **measurement** to reference **recorded_on** in the table called **sample**
The column **Recorded on** in the **Sample** table must be part of a composite key together with **Scientist_Num**
The error is coming from
     FOREIGN KEY (Recorded_On) REFERENCES Sample(Scientist, Recorded_On, Site_ID)

```
CREATE TABLE Sample (
Scientist_Num varchar2(5) not null,
Recorded_On date not null,
Site_ID varchar2(4) not null,
Comments clob,
Primary key (Scientist_Num, Recorded_On),
FOREIGN KEY (Scientist_Num) REFERENCES Scientist(Scientist_Num),
FOREIGN KEY (Site_ID) REFERENCES Site(Site_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Measurement (
Site_ID varchar2(4) not null,
Recorded_On date not null,
Name varchar2(10) not null,
Value varchar2(10),
Outlier_Indicator varchar2(10),
Primary key (Site_ID, Recorded_On, Name),
FOREIGN KEY (Site_ID) REFERENCES Sample(Site_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Recorded_On) REFERENCES Sample(Scientist, Recorded_On, Site_ID)
);
```

**The Scientist_Num and Recorded_On columns must be in a composite key together.**

The answer to my problem and an explanation of what went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. The foreign key columns must match a key in the referenced table.

Comment: I don't understand what the key in the reference table should be. I tried just having Sample: Recorded_On  as the referenced column and that didn't work either

Comment: Neither do I. As I said, a foreign key references a key. Must have same number of column, and matching data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual column in sample table:

```
Recorded_virtual varchar2(5) [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS 
(Scientist||Recorded_On||Site_ID) [VIRTUAL]
```

And create reference to this column:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_column
 FOREIGN KEY (Recorded_On)
 REFERENCES Sample(Recorded_virtual )
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key references need to match the primary keys in number and type.  So I think you intend:

```
CREATE TABLE Measurement (
    Site_ID varchar2(4) not null,
    Scientist_Num varchar2(5) not null,
----^ added for foreign key reference
    Recorded_On date not null,
    Name varchar2(10) not null,
    Value varchar2(10),
    Outlier_Indicator varchar2(10),
    Primary key (Site_ID, Recorded_On, Name),
    FOREIGN KEY (Site_ID) REFERENCES Site(Site_ID),
-------------------------------------^ Presumably you intend the site table
    FOREIGN KEY (Scientist_Num, Recorded_On) REFERENCES 
Sample(Scientist_Num, Recorded_On)
-----------------^ two columns, both need to already be defined
);
```

I suspect there are other issues with your data model, but this should fix the syntax error.  If you want further help, then ask *another* question.

Comment: @Jajimal . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?